# How to return values assigned to a specific row in column order?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame that looks like this and stretches for millions of rows:

```
          id       class weight
1:   3930271          77    1.0
2:   3930272          55    0.5
3:   3930272         654    0.5
4:   3930273          66    0.5
5:   3930273          66    0.5
6:   3930274         225    1.0
7:   3930275          66   0.05
7:   3930275          44   0.05
...
...
34'000'000:
```

That's because each class appears multiple times within the same id. The weight column measures the fractional value of each class to the patent (patent with 2 classes means that each class contributes 0.5). 
Now, I would like to reduce the number of rows by simply having one patent_id and multiple classes (from 1 to max 20) in the same row. What I want looks like this:

```
          id      class1 class2  ... class20  weight
1:   3930271          77      0            0       1
2:   3930272          55    654            0     0.5
3:   3930273          65     66            0     0.5
4:   3930274         225      0            0       1
5:   3930275          66     44           30    0.05
6:   3930276         225     33            0     0.5
```

Some id will not have 20 classes, therefore it should return a 0 or a dot in that case. There is no criteria to select class when it has more than 20 values since it happens only a few times compared to the millions of id. 
Some patent_id will have more than 20 classes but I want to exclude those (few observations). 
How would you do that?
I tried the function spread of tidyr but it reports this error message

```
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
```

That's because sometimes the value of class repeat itself, but I need to keep it as it is.

Comment: You should clarify the logic of `class2` to `class20` - where are the values coming from and how is `weight` calculated?

Comment: does each `patent_id` have 20 classes, or would you just fill the rest in with `0`? Do some have more than 20 classes?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: u can to use `tidyr::spread()`.

Comment: Good question. There is no criteria to select class when it has more than 20 values since it happens only a few times compared to the millions of id. Frankly, I would rather exclude those id that have more than 20 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely a much cleaner way to accomplish this task. Read up on tidyr::spread() and gather(), and data.table::dcast(), melt(), and cast().

Using your provided sample data:

```
sample_data <- data.frame("id" = c(3930271, 3930272, 3930272,
                                   3930273, 3930273, 3930274, 
                                   3930275, 3930275),
                          "class" = c(77, 55, 654, 
                                      66, 66, 225, 
                                      66, 44),
                          "weight" = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
                                       0.5, 1, 0.05, 0.05))
```

Use dplyr's summarize function to aggregate each id's class values. This will filter to exclude any id with more than 20 class unique class values.

```
 library(dplyr) #imports the group_by, summarize, filter, select, and bind_cols functions
 library(magrittr) #imports the %>% pipe function
 library(tidyr) #imports the separate function

wide_df_new <- sample_data %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarize(class_list = list(class),
             n = n(),
             weight = 1/n) %>%
   filter(n <= 20) %>%
   select(-n)
```

Create a vector of new column names:

```
 new_col_names <- paste0("class", 1:20)
```

Each id has a list of it's classes contained in a single column of the dataframe, `sample_data$class_list` (a list within a list). Split this single list into the new columns.

```
wide_df_new <- separate(wide_df_new , col = class_list, 
                        into = new_col_names, 
                        remove = TRUE,
                        sep = ", ")
```

Remove the character vector artifacts from the columns. This will remove all nonnumeric character from all columns! convert back to numeric and bind columns to return to a dataframe datastructure.

```
wide_df_new <- lapply(wide_df_new  , function(x) gsub("[^0-9\\.]", "", x)) %>%
lapply(as.numeric) %>% 
bind_cols()
```

Last but not least, fill all NA values with 0.

```
wide_df_new[is.na(wide_df_new)] <- 0
```

Like I said originally, there is probably a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Neat! Your first reply was near perfection. The only issue from that reply is that I get a wrong value for the fractional count weight. The second one reports an error: Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('standardGeneric', 'genericFunction', 'function', 'OptionalFunction', 'PossibleMethod', 'optionalMethod')"

Comment: @MatteoTraversini Thanks for checking. I revised the summarize function call to include the proper calculation for the weight variable. Try reimporting the dplyr library with `library(dplyr)`. It's possible another package is overriding group_by in the environment. The code runs without error on my machine.

Comment: @MatteoTraversini if you like to keep the ids with more than 20 class values, but ignore any values after the 20th for each id, remove the filter line and modify the `separate` function call to include the `extra = "drop"` parameter. The number of class values and associated columns can be controlled with the sequence used to define new_col_names.

Comment: I tried again but the weight does not work still. Also, the way of cleaning NA you provide in the data set goes Armageddon and reduces my data to 0.

Comment: @MatteoTraversini changed `wide_df_new <- wide_df_new[is.na(wide_df_new)] <- 0` to `wide_df_new[is.na(wide_df_new)] <- 0`. Perhaps I am confused about the weight column. Is weight a numeric value defined  by 1/(number of classes associated with a specific id)? Or is it merely carried over from the original dataset?

Comment: It is 1/(number of classes associated with a specific ID)

Comment: @MatteoTraversini the key was removing the unique() function when creating a list of all the class attributes associated with an id. I'm 99% confident that this will now work as expected. Sorry for the run-around!

Comment: What sorry?! You are my hero :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` answer that should give you the output you desire.  The trick is to get the numbering using the special symbol `.N` within `data.table` which will create the sequence you want for the classes in a dynamic way. Here is the sample data and note I converted it to a `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
sample_data <- data.table("id" = c(3930271, 3930272, 3930272,
                               3930273, 3930273, 3930274, 
                               3930275, 3930275),
                      "class" = c(77, 55, 654, 
                                  65, 66, 225, 
                                  66, 44),
                      "weight" = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
                                   0.5, 1, 0.05, 0.05))
```

EDIT:   I just realized you only want the first 20 occurrences of an ID and so added that to my answer. Or alternatively do you want to remove all instances of the IDs occurring greater than 20 times? Please clarify.

```
melt_dt<-sample_data[,melt(.SD,measure.vars=c("class"))]
melt_dt[,id_count:=seq_len(.N),by="id"][id_count<=20][,colname_val:=paste0("class",id_count)]

wide_dt<-dcast(melt_dt,id+weight~colname_val, value.var="value",fill=0)
```

So first just melt and specify "class" as your measurement variable. Then create a variable which will count the number of the same IDs. If you only want the first 20 occurrences then select only the rows with 20 or less as shown in second chain of `melted_dt`. Finally append these numbers to "class" to get the naming scheme you desire in a variable called `colname_val`. Finally you can create your wide shaped `data.table` using `dcast` and adding the `fill=0` argument to replace the `NAs`. Is this helpful?  Let me know if you need me to clarify anything. Good luck!

Comment: +1. The data.table methods are going to operate significantly faster than the dplyr alternatives, particularly with 34million rows.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with data.table

```
library(data.table)
sample_data[, ri := paste0("class",seq_len(.N)), by=.(id, weight)]
ans <- dcast(sample_data[ri<=20], id + weight ~ ri, value.var="class")
ans[, names(ans) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))]
ans
```

Comment: Third line of code returns this error: Error in CJ(1:5866126, 1:1109) : 
  Cross product of elements provided to CJ() would result in 6505533734 rows which exceeds .Machine$integer.max == 2147483647

Comment: added something to try to address it. can you share some stats about your data? like the number of unique elements in id and weight columns?